# Apply a function to a random row of a matrix

Tags: apl, dyalog

I have a 5x5 matrix `M` and a function `f` that operates on vectors. `r ← ⊃?⍴M` is the index of a random row of `M`. I need to return a modified version of `M` without direct assignment (it's important for the larger program) where `f` is only applied to `r⌷M`. I'm doing this by mapping across `M`'s rows, returning `f⍵` if the row's index matches r, and just `⍵` if it doesn't. The function I came up with is:

```
({f(⍣(r = M⍳⍵))⍵}⍤1) M
```

It works, but it's not ideal. I don't like the `r = M⍳⍵` part, because I'm searching for the index of `⍵` in every cycle. I think it'd make more sense to operate across `⍳5` instead, referencing each row in terms of each `⍵` in this vector. I can't seem to get this to work though.

Any help making my function less ugly is appreciated.

Comment: Btw, you should use `r←?≢M` instead of  `r←⊃?⍴M`. Monadic `≢` is *tally*, which is the number of major cells, so the number of rows of a matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`f@r⊢M`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/dR2wRTBdNHvVse9W42MuVKA/J1uYqA5KOuZnugsC/Xo76pQG6aQ9GjrkW@//8DAA)­

Example code:

```
M←5 5⍴⍳25
f←-
r←⊃?⍴M
⎕←f@r⊢M
```

Example result:

```
 1  2  3  4   5
¯6 ¯7 ¯8 ¯9 ¯10
11 12 13 14  15
16 17 18 19  20
21 22 23 24  25
```

Comment: Very cool, thank you. I'm not sure what the right tack is doing here though. `f@r⌷M` yields a similar result. Is there a reason to prefer the former?

Comment: `⊢` prevents `r` and `M` from "stranding" (forming a vector). Another way to do that is with parentheses: `(f@r)M`. Note that `r` is not the left argument to `⊢` (or `⌷` in your example) but the right operand to `@`, which is a dyadic operator.

Comment: @IanMartin The difference between monadic `⊢` and monadic `⌷` is that `⌷` will materialise the default property of a class and the constituent members of a collection object, while `⊢` is a true no-op.